# Step by step guide to buid for distribution in 4.6 Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have tested my app on my iphone device on iOS 4.6 and it works fine. I am ready to build for App Store – here my problems start.
I cannot find/change the path where to build the app 
When I press Run to ">iOS Device", it wants to connect to my iPhone

Is there a step by step guide to build for distribution in 4.6 Xcode? I can find one for 4.2 but not for 4.6

Comment: Don't you just use *Archive*?

Answer (score 1):

**App Store Submission Tutorial**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html

You just Archive your app and submit from the Xcode Organizer. In the Xcode Organizer select the Archives tab and click the "Distribute..." button.

[image]